# how to select columns based on row values

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there any way to filter a data.frame like this? I'd like to keep all the rows and column where a certain sub string occurs, as well as the next column.

```
 df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = 
                       "date    col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
                     1  boston    22    new_york   15     atlanta    5
                     2  boston    21    new_york   15      atlanta   0

                     ")

cities <- c('boston', 'atlanta')
#filter by cities
#output 
#col2   col3 col5    col6
#boston   22 atlanta    5
#boston   21 atlanta    0
```

Answer (score 0):

We loop through the alternate columns of dataset, check whether all the elements are `%in%` cities to create a logical vector ('i1'), then based on the index, get the column index of the TRUE column and the next column

```
i1 <- sapply(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], function(x) all(x %in% cities))
df[sort(which(names(df) %in% names(i1)[i1]) + rep(0:1,  each = 2))]
```

---

Or another option is to loop through the sequence of alternate column index, subset the dataset, check `if` all the elements are found in 'cities', then subset the column and the next column (`df[i:(i+1)]`), `Fiter` out the `list` elements that are NULL and `cbind` the remaining elements

```
 do.call(cbind, Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by = 2),
               function(i) if(all(df[,i] %in% cities)) df[i:(i+1)])))
```